# Some icons of Font-awesome don't work (wordpress 3.9.1)

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I'm using wordpress 3.9.1 and Theme Roxy Bird. In this theme I can use the icons of font-awesome; just have to fill in e.a. icon-glass.

But some icons don't work; e.g. icon-microphone which I really realy like, and icon-share-alt.

Does someone know why, and what to do?

Thanks! Myra

Answer (score 0):

According to font-awesome there isn't an icon named 'icon-microphone' on their list. Check here and rename it: http://fontawesome.io/icons/